# node.js res.write doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js

To learn node js i make some exercise but have got a problem, the "res" variable work in index.js but doesn't work in the  fs.exists function, why ?. Thanks for your responses.

server.js

```
var http = require("http");
global.PATH = __dirname;

http.createServer(function(req, res) {


    var app = require("./index.js")(req, res);

    res.end();

}).listen(8080);
```

index.js

```
var url = require("url");
var fs  = require("fs");

module.exports = function(req, res){


    if(req){

        var pathname  = url.parse(req.url).pathname.split("/");
        pathname.splice(0,1);
        var action = pathname[1];


        fs.exists(PATH + "/" + pathname[0] + ".js" , function(exist){

            var controller;
            res.write('doesn\'t work');

            if(exist)
            {
                if(!controller){
                    controller = require(PATH + "/controllers/" + pathname[0] + ".js" )();

                    if(controller[action])
                        controller[action]();
                 }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `require()` is synchronous, so I don't recommend you use it in each request. Cache it first, then make calls to the file you're requiring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i don't know why some of you downvoted the question, because for a beginner some asynchronous patterns could be confusing...

first of all you should cache your require-call (as Seth mentioned).

```
global.PATH = __dirname;
var http = require("http");
var app = require("./index"); //omit .js, you don't need it
```

then you you index.js you are using fs.exists, which is asynchronous. that means, that the `res.end()` is called before your callback function inside `fs.exists` is reached, which means the request/response lifecylcle is over.

you could use [fs.existsSync](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_existssync_path) (not recommended!) or  provide some callback which you call when done!

2 more things

1. the `if(req)` is unneccessary, there is always a request object!
2. you ALWAYS need to call the callback in your function, to make the response be sent!

**server.js:**

```
http.createServer(function(req, res) {

    app(req, res, function () {
      res.end();
    });

}).listen(8080);
```

**index.js:**

```
var url = require("url");
var fs  = require("fs");

module.exports = function(req, res, cb) {  // see third cb-argument!


    var pathname  = url.parse(req.url).pathname.split("/");
    pathname.splice(0,1);
    var action = pathname[1];


    fs.exists(PATH + "/" + pathname[0] + ".js" , function(exist){

        var controller;
        res.write('doesn\'t work');

        if(exist)
        {
            if(!controller){
                controller = require(PATH + "/controllers/" + pathname[0] + ".js" )();

                if(controller[action])
                    controller[action]();
             }
        }
        cb(); // whenever you're done call the callback
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response i understood, it so stupid furthermore i known that fs.exists is asynchronous.